# Koa - Catch all routes that start with prefix

Tags: koa, koa-router

I was wondering how can we catch all API call of a specific route with KOA-Router.
For example. I have an api designed like this :

```
/api/
/api/user/
/api/user/create
/api/user/login
/api/user/delete
```

How can I trigger the route `/api/` for all calls that start with `/api/` ? With expressJS you could do something like this to get all calls that start with a specific path:

```
app.get('/api/*', ()=>{});
```

but with KOA, the star '*' doesn't work, and I can't find something usefull inside the KOA documentation. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer inside the path-to-regexp github readme. Koa use this for it's path matching.

https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp

They have an example showing how to do this :

```
const regexp = pathToRegexp("/:foo/(.*)");
```

So I just need to put `(.*)` instead of a simple `*`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick exmaple. Make sure you call `next()` from the **/api** route to pass the request down the middleware stack.

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const Router = require('@koa/router')

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

router.get('/api(.*)', (ctx, next) => {
  ctx.body = 'You hit the /api route'
  next()
})

router.get('/api/user', (ctx) => {
  ctx.body += '\nYou hit the /api/user route'
})

router.get('/api/user/create', (ctx) => {
  ctx.body += '\nYou hit the /api/user/create route'
})

app.use(router.routes())

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to know this also works:

```
router.get("/static/:path(.*)", async function(ctx, next) {
  console.log(ctx.params);
  next();
});
```

Result:

```
{ path: 'test/1/2/3' }
```